# Apache Beam Python word count example is failing for Flink Runner with BeamIOError

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to run Apache Beam Python word count example on Apache 's Flink using PortableRunner using a SDK harness/Job Server via Docker.

1. Built SDK harness container using `./gradlew -p sdks/python/container docker`. But when doing docker pull on the image created, it gives below error :

   > Using default tag: latest
   >   Error response from daemon: Get https://$userId-docker- 
   >   apache.bintray.io/v2/: 
   >   x509: certificate is valid for *.bintray.io, bintray.io, not $userId-docker- 
   >   apache.bintray.io
2. Successfully started the Flink portable Jobservice endpoint using `./gradlew beam-runners-flink_2.11-job-server:runShadow`.

But when trying to run the wordcount example using below command with PortableRunner,

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input=local_input_file --output=local_output_file --job_endpoint=localhost:8099 --experiments beam_fn_api --runner=PortableRunner
```

it gives the below error:

> IOError as “RuntimeError: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory:
>   '/beam-temp-output-b6d55cb671ef11e9be2f025000000001/3ce015aa-78ee-4bfa-be17-120de259e690.output'
>   [while running 'write/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite’]”

Running with DirectRunner instead of PortableRunner gets it to work fine though! 
Any hint about how i can get the wordcount to work with PortableRunner via Docker is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying repository name and pull from there? (by using -Pdocker-repository-root)

something like this:

"./gradlew -Pdocker-repository-root=gcr.io/SOME_NAME_HERE -p sdks/go/container docker"

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. Try this:

```
./gradlew docker
```

Relevant documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/CONTAINERS.md)